# css - unexpected position of span in side a content area

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using `react-pro-sidebar` as the side bar.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar />
      <span>Why is this span here?</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I am expecting:
[image]

But actually:
[image]

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-mayer-dhem4?file=/src/Navbar/index.js

**Update 1**

Why wouldn't it happen in the demo?
https://azouaoui-med.github.io/react-pro-sidebar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nikola is correct but its important to understand why this is happening. I assume NavBar is a display block element, and in that case it will take up the full available width. Therefor the span element will end up being rendered under it.

One of the possible solutions is to make their container's display property be `flex`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make `.App` as `display: flex;` if that's what you looking for

Comment: look at `.app` class, it is set to `display: flex`

Answer (score 1):

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;  
}
```

Comment: .app {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}